# Accessing variable value

Tags: javascript, html

I am accessing a html file using readFileSync like this

```
 var content = fs.readFileSync("client/index.html", "utf-8");
```

and passing content to html.

```
Students.afterRemote('create', function(ctx, result, next) {
 loopback.Email.send({
            to: result.email,
            from: "person1@something.com",
            subject: "Thanks for choosing Us",
            text: "text message",
            html: content,
            var: {
                myVar1: 'a custom value'
            },
            headers: {
                "X-My-Header": "My Custom header"
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
        });
}
```

In my html file I have this code

```
    result.name + "<p> Your account is created successfully.Thanks for creating an account</p>"
```

In email it is not giving me result.name's value. It is displaying result.name. How can I access its value? Thanks

Comment: You never define `result`. I get the impression that you have provided a couple of fragments of code without trying to make a proper [mcve]

Comment: The [tag:loopback] tag doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: I am getting correct result.Question is how can I access it?

Comment: How should I know? I told you that you needed to provide more information. You haven't provided more information. Assurances that something is "correct" don't help anyone understand how your code gets from A to C when B is entirely missing from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have something that looks like JavaScript code inside a string, then it is still just part of that string. It will not be executed as if it was JavaScript code.

```js
var result = { name: "bar" };
var string = `    result.name + "<p> Your account is created successfully.Thanks for creating an account</p>"`;
console.log(string);
```

If you want to use variables, then you'll need to write them in JavaScript and not in a text file you read into a variable.

```js
var result = { name: "bar" };
var string = `<p> Your account is created successfully.Thanks for creating an account</p>`;
var output = result.name + string;
console.log(output);
```

You could put placeholders in the file and then use a replace call…

```js
var result = { name: "bar" };
var string = `<<<name>>><p> Your account is created successfully.Thanks for creating an account</p>`;
string = string.replace("<<<name>>>", result.name);
console.log(string);
```

… but at that stage you are creating your own template language and should probably be picking [an off the shelf option](https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) like [Nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks)

```js
var result = { name: "bar" };
var template = `{{ name }}<p> Your account is created successfully.Thanks for creating an account</p>`;

console.log(nunjucks.renderString(template, result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nunjucks/3.0.1/nunjucks.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.Appreciate your help.